# How can I use a for loop to update diagonals in my covariance matrix?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, correlation

I have created simulation data for two variables using mvrnorms and I want to correlate these variables 0, .5, .7, and .9 within a loop. But every-time I run my for loop I can only correlate the values at .9 and not at any of the other correlation conditions.

```
library(MASS) #library I needed to create simulated data with mvrnorms

num_iter <- 75
N <- 30                       # setting my sample size
mu <- c(50.5, 10.5)           # setting the std
R <- c(0,.5,.7,.9)            # this vector defines the different correlation conditions I will add

# saving files
dir.create("simulated1data") # This creates a directory to store files

# performing 75 iterations and so there should be 75 data files in the folder I made
for(i in 1:num_iter){
  for(j in 1:4){
    cov <- matrix(c(1,R[j],R[j],1),2,2)
    x <- mvrnorm(N,mu,cov)
    write.table(x, file=paste("simulated1data/simdata_",i,"_",j,".txt",sep="")) # writing to separate txt file
  }
}
```

From my understanding, my (for j in 1:4) is not appropriately running through all the jth values in my R vector which is why the variables in X are always correlated at .9. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign the values of `R`, create a `cov` matrix beforehand and use a logical index matrix, `imat`.

The first code block is like in the question.

```
library(MASS) #library I needed to create simulated data with mvrnorms

num_iter <- 75
N <- 30                       # setting my sample size
mu <- c(50.5, 10.5)           # setting the std
R <- c(0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9)      # this vector defines the different correlation conditions I will add
```

This is to test on my system.

```
# saving files
dirsimdata <- "~/tmp/simulated1data"
dir.create(dirsimdata) # This creates a directory to store files
```

Now the `cov` and `imat` matrices.

```
# index matrix used to assign values from R
imat <- matrix(c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), nrow = 2)
# start with all 1's
cov <- matrix(1, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

And finally, the double `for` loops.

```
# performing 75 iterations and so there should be 75 data files in the folder I made
for(i in 1:num_iter){
  for(j in 1:4){
    cov[imat] <- R[j]
    x <- mvrnorm(N, mu, cov)
    flname <- paste0("simdata_", i, "_", j, ".txt")
    flname <- file.path(dirsimdata, flname)
    write.table(x, file = flname) # writing to separate txt file
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any error in your code. You mistakenly identify `mu` as the standard deviation, but it is the mean for each variable and the `R` is the covariance not the correlation. You set the standard deviation for each variable at `1` in the covariance matrix. If I set `num_iter <- 2` and use `set.seed(42)` before entering the loop, I get reasonable correlations considering the sample size is only 30:

```
cor(read.table("simulated1data/simdata_1_1.txt"))
#          V1       V2
# V1 1.000000 0.204011
# V2 0.204011 1.000000
cor(read.table("simulated1data/simdata_1_2.txt"))
#           V1        V2
# V1 1.0000000 0.2706851
# V2 0.2706851 1.0000000
cor(read.table("simulated1data/simdata_1_3.txt"))
#           V1        V2
# V1 1.0000000 0.6727047
# V2 0.6727047 1.0000000
cor(read.table("simulated1data/simdata_1_4.txt"))
#           V1        V2
# V1 1.0000000 0.9306898
# V2 0.9306898 1.0000000
cor(read.table("simulated1data/simdata_2_1.txt"))
#            V1         V2
# V1 1.00000000 0.06184222
# V2 0.06184222 1.00000000
cor(read.table("simulated1data/simdata_2_2.txt"))
#           V1        V2
# V1 1.0000000 0.3686962
# V2 0.3686962 1.0000000
cor(read.table("simulated1data/simdata_2_3.txt"))
#           V1        V2
# V1 1.0000000 0.7660853
# V2 0.7660853 1.0000000
cor(read.table("simulated1data/simdata_2_4.txt"))
#           V1        V2
# V1 1.0000000 0.8589621
# V2 0.8589621 1.0000000
```